# Can not downgrade bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am getting this error while trying to push my app to heroku:
`Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.17.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running`gem install bundler`.` I have the following versions of bundler:

```
gem list | grep bundler
bundler (2.0.2, default: 1.17.3, 1.17.2)
```

I have tried various suggestions from different similar posts but I am not able to set the bundler version to 1.17.2 which is required by Heroku. I tried:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler -v 1.17.2
1 gem installed
```

Then removed the lock file and rerunning the `bundle update` but the version 1.17.3 still comes as the default.

I tried `gem uninstall bundler:1.17.3` which returned:

```
Successfully uninstalled bundler-1.17.3
```

Then: `gem install bundler -v 1.17.2`which returned:

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.2
1 gem installed
```

Now `bundler -v` returns a `LoadError:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    2: from /home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    1: from /home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>'
/home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/bundler:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/amairu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundler (LoadError)
```

I am using rvm and I also tried to uninstall in the global gem set:

`rvm use 2.6.1@global`

`gem uninstall bundler:1.17.3` which does not return any output or message.

How can I set the bundler to 1.17.2?

Comment: Sometimes that issue is solved by opening a new terminal window

Answer (score 0):

set your bundler version as a default version like below if you want to use 2.0.2

```
bundle _2.0.2_ -v
```

Comment: `bundle _2.0.2_ -v` returns the error
`Could not find command "_2.0.2_".`

Comment: give me result of 'gem list bundler'

Comment: `gem list bundler`

`*** LOCAL GEMS ***`

`bundler (2.0.2, default: 1.17.3, 1.17.2)`
`bundler-unload (1.0.2)`
`rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)`

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with bundlers recently (Bundler v2.0.2 was installed, v1.17.3 set as default) but with a different error (`Can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)`).

Running `gem update --system` did a trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install the correct bundler for your application with the following command:

`gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"`